# SQL Count (*) function with dates

Tags: mysql

How do I use the count (*) function within a set date parameter? I have a table of order records and I would like to only count the ones for a specific date.

My Query was

```
SELECT COUNT (*) 
FROM bets
WHERE order_date='2018-01-22';
```

And that returned this

> 1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings

```
cQuery: SELECT COUNT (*) FROM bets WHERE order_date='2018-01-22' LIMIT 0, 1000
```

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '*)  FROM bets WHERE order_date='2018-01-22' LIMIT
>   0, 1000' at line 1
>
> Execution Time : 0 sec Transfer Time  : 0 sec Total Time     : 0.021
>   sec

Answer (score 4):

Remove the space between `count` and `()`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The above works in **Postgres**, **mysql** needs set **`sql_mode = "IGNORE_SPACE";`**.

> That why this gives you an error there two way either you can remove
>   space or set sql_mode.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried and mentioned query is working for me:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM "**TABLENAME**"  where  DATE_FORMAT(**columnName**,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2017-08-02';
```